# Not able to Enter Text in a TextBox using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a TextBox that appears on Radio Button Selection and I have to enter values in a particular format(XYZ989898-99). However I am unable to do so by using the commonly used methods of entering text in selenium.

Background info related to Textbox :

1. TextBox appears when user clicks on Yes radio button.
2. TextBox has default value as XYZ already entered.
3. SendKeys do not concatenate the text given without XYZ as well.
4. TextBox is inside an Iframe to which focus is shifted correctly.
5. The code does not fail, it just remained clicked on textbox without entering anything.

Approach 1 :

```
      driver.findElement(locator).SendKeys("989898-99");
```

Approach 2 :

```
      driver.findElement(locator).clear();
      driver.findElement(locator).SendKeys("XYZ989898-99");
```

Approach 3 :

```
      WebElement element =  driver.findElement(locator);
      Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
      action1.movetoElement(element).click().perform();
      action1.sendKeys("XYZ989898-99");
```

HTML Sample :

```
        <div class="value" ng-show="selectedValue" style="">
            <label class="labelAboveTextBox">XYZ Number*</label>
            <input type="text" class="Value" ng-model="XYZNumber" ng- 
            req="XYZNumber" xyz-input="" maxlength="12" style="value" 
            id="value" value="XYZ" required="required">
            <!-- ngIf: invalidtspmessage -->
            <span style="font-family: 'NeueHaasGroteskText';font-size: 
            0.7rem;color: black;">
            Note: Enter XYZ is this format: XXXXXXXXX-XX
            </span>
        </div>
```

I would like to know If there is any other approach that can be used to get this problem resolved and also why does the above approaches failed to work.

Comment: Can you please share html here?

Comment: Hey @KajalKundu Shared the HTML sample here. Iframe switching is happening perfectly fine and the code is able to click/clear the textbox as well.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @kovid mehta, Can you share the locator that you are using for sending the text?

Comment: Hey @MosheSlavin I am using Java as the language here.

Comment: Hey @AliCSE The locator is Xpath : "//input[@id='Value']"

Comment: @kovidmehta, try `//input[@id='value']` instead of `//input[@id='Value']`

Comment: Hey @AliCSE "Value" here is just for indicating purpose. So the locator is perfectly fine and is unique as well. Not the issue with Locator for sure.

Comment: Ok @kovidmehta, give some delay before and after clicking and try to enter the text.

Comment: I assume you are using the Java, try the `JavaScriptExecutor` like this `Thread.sleep(3000);
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('value').value='XYZ989898-99';");` and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: @AliCSE That Works ! Thanks alot, but still I am a bit unclear about how did other approaches failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way you can use is to set the text is by using the JavaScriptExecutor. Give some delay before performing the action.

Try the below sample code :

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('value').value='XYZ989898-99';");
```

As the id is unique, you can use the JavaScript's `getElementById()` function to set the value.

If you want to set the text through the `sendKeys()` method and before that if you want to clear the text then simple `clear()` may not work instead you can try to delete the `XYZ` values first and try to send the values like below again :

```
// Wait for some time
Thread.sleep(3000);
// Locate the element first and store it in some variable
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("value"));
// Fetch the existing text from the field first
String existingValue = element.getAttribute("value");
// Wait for some time
Thread.sleep(3000);
// Click on that element first so the focus will shift to there
element.click();
// Wait for some time
Thread.sleep(2000);
// Loop until the existing value length
for(int i=0;i<existingValue.length();i++) {
    // Remove the existing character text one by one
    element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
}
// Try to send the text at the end, make sure that you should append XYZ as a prefix
element.sendKeys("XYZ989898-99");
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Hey Ali, Thanks I tried with the Javascript Approach yesterday and It worked. I will give a try on Keys.BACK_SPACE as well and update the thread. But to summarize the solution you provided worked.

Answer (score 2):

- You have used the wrong methods for sending the keys. (in approach 1 and 2)
- Instead of .SendKeys(), you have to use .sendKeys() method for writing anything on UI side
- Into the third approach, you have used the wrong method .movetoElement(). The method name is .moveToElement().
- For sendKeys() don't need to use Actions class. basically, it is for Keyboard events and for mouse events.

  (WebElement).sendKeys("989898-99"); // first approach you can use

  (WebElement).clear();         // second approach you can use

  (WebElement).sendKeys("XYZ989898-99");

Hope this will help you to solve your errors.

Comment: Sorry Yash but that's not the solution. I have just mentioned the approach with these lines of code and Eclipse takes care to correct the Method Names if they are mis-spelt. So you can Ignore this case while I confirm that there are no syntax error in the approaches mentioned above.